# Phonegap Hybrid App - Device Compatibility

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, ionic-framework, onsen-ui

What is good UI framework for Phonegap app?  My highest priority is compatibility with older devices. Ionic looks promising. But it supports newer devices only. Tried Onsenui. It is simple and straight forward. But it seems OnsenUi is not tested with different devices.  When I checked Jquery Mobile docs, it supports older version of Android also. So is Jquery Mobile a better UI framework in terms of compatibility for hybrid mobile apps?

Answer (score 1):

you can try out http://dojotoolkit.org/
It has support for mobile platform as well 
You can look at the **MOBILE** demos here
http://demos.dojotoolkit.org/demos/

The Mobile has support for Android/IPhone, Blackberyy, Windows OS out of box and compatibility with **OLDER devices**.

There are many features in dojo toolkit. I am just mentioning you a few of them.
feature link : http://dojotoolkit.org/features/

1)it is **free** to use for **both commercial and non-commercial use**.

2) Multilanguage Support
3) Built in Automated testing framework.
4) Build framework ( Building packages, Minification, Optimization, Obfuscation etc.)

It also had good enough tutorial. Refer:http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/

It is supported by IBM, MOZILLA etc.